# How to prevent a file from being deleted even after uninstalling the application in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I want to prevent my file from being deleted by user or any other app. In this file I have to save a long value and some information. I have used `SharedPreferences` and `SQLite` database in order to store those information. But I noticed that if my application get uninstalled or cleared data, the database or `SharedPreferences` also deleted. Now I am thinking that I will save data in that file and protect it from any kind of deletion. So that my app will be able to restore data anytime even after uninstall. Is it possible?

Comment: To survive uninstall you should save the data on the external storage, but there is no way to prevent user from deleting or formatting it.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to enforce some persistent licensing or trial periods. If you want to create a persistent value, you'd have to go outside of your app's sandbox; access to external storage has been greatly hampered in recent version of Android. You might want to keep track of those values off-device instead.

Comment: Just copy the information on a server.

Answer (score 2):

The best you'll be able to do is save the data as a File on the Android file system. You'll need to add the write external storage permission to your manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Check out the Android File API here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

It's relatively straightforward. You'll want to save the file somewhere that won't be deleted when your app is uninstalled, so perhaps in a folder on the SD card.

However, there's no guarantee that the user or some other app (although I don't know how many apps go around deleting arbitrary files) won't delete the file manually. If you actually need guaranteed ultra-persistence, then I suggest storing the files on the cloud or on a server.

Comment: Can you provide some tutorial of cloud storage. I have seen some code. But I am not clear.

Comment: That's going to be a bit more involved, and will depend on what you're trying to achieve. Your best bet would be to store the file on a server somewhere, associated with the user somehow (perhaps their user account, or their device ID). If you're just trying to restore user settings or something similar, then storing on the device should suit your needs.

If 323go is right and you're trying to create something like a "trial period", then using a server for authentication is a far better solution than trying to do it all client-side.